# trace of exterior product of a skew matrix $M$, $\bigwedge^kM$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, exterior-algebra

is there a characterisation of the trace of a skew-matrix $M$ (say $n\times n$)? Clearly for $k=1$ we have $\bigwedge^kM=M$ hence the trace is zero, (since $M$ is skew).

What about $k=2$ and $k=3$? my intuition tells me that the trace of $\bigwedge^3M$ should vanish, but I can't relate it to the one of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traces of $\bigwedge^k M$ are, up to sign, the coefficients in the characteristic equation of $M$, and so the elementary symmetric functions in the eigenvalues of $M$.

Over a field of characteristic not two, the non-zero eigenvalues of a
skew-symmetric matrix $M$ always fall into pairs $\lambda$, $-\lambda$.
Therefore for odd $k$ the trace of $\bigwedge^k M$ is always zero.
For even $k$, the $k$-th elementary
symmetric function of the eigenvalues is the $(k/2)$-th elementary
symmetric function of the $-\lambda^2$ as above.

Comment: yeah, realised now I forgot to mention we are working over the complex field.

Comment: it's unclear to me why the odd-degree terms must be zero. Can you elaborate?

Comment: An alternative argument for the odd case is that the trace on the $k$-th exterior power is the sum of $\binom nk$ determinants of size $k$ skew symmetric matrices. All these determinants vanish.